# Http Error 404:14 - Forbidden

Tags: asp.net, web, iis-7.5

I've installed my web application already in IIS. But when we run it, it contains HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden. I've researched about the solutions.

1. Enabled Directory Browsing.
   -But enabling directory browsing is not allowed.
2. Add Defalut Document
   -I already have a default Document.

So now, I'm practically lost on how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already solved this issue. There's just something wrong with my default document in my web.config. I used ~/Login.aspx instead of Login.aspx.

`<defaultDocument enabled="true">
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="Login.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>`

Answer (score 1):

Have you already registered the framework for iis in the computer?

```
C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319> .\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319> iisreset
```

run that in command prompt

Note: Path will of course change depending on your local drive

Comment: Ensure that the account running IIS has permission to read/write on the folder that your application is installed. Where are you hosting this site? What is your default document and how is your IIS configured? What is the IIS App pool setting (ASP.NET 2 or 4)?